# Wordpress custom post type archive and single.php files not working

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi I've created a custom post type called shows.

here is the code for it. [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/5TKVdFmj)

I've created 2 files that follow accordingly to the wordpress hierarchy and called them archive-shows.php and single-shows.php. These should automatically link to the correct pages however for some reason they both default back to index.php.

Fix's tried
Permalinks Flushed
has archive = true

please any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Try Wordpress Admin => Settings => Permalinks and choose anything else then "Default"

Comment: Sounds like your htaccess is messed up.  Or maybe you don't have `mod_rewrite` enabled on your server (an apache module that allows for pretty permalinks)

Comment: I'm on my local server thats maybe why? just using wamp

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your .htaccess file has the correct permissions to be writable.

Comment: what conditions are these scott sorry, I'll paste my .htaccess file in here.

Comment: # BEGIN WordPress

# END WordPress

Comment: Really, it is the directory which contains the file. See this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308419